# The year and date of 1900 keeps appearing when I link one cell to another empty cell on a separate page

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Right now I am trying to link the dates between two pages.

So, when someone fills out the date using the shorthand, Ctrl + ;, then the current date will appear.

When the person inputs the date, a cell on a different sheet will say the same date.

I have multiple "Property" tabs and each tab will be reviewed on different days. When the reviewer finishes his/her reviewing, they will shorthand the date in the designated cell and that cell is linked to the Summary tab, a tab that shows all of the property's reviewed dates.

In the Summary tab, I have pre-formatted the linked cells to be under the category of "Date" and then I chose a particular "Type."

The issue I am facing is this:

when there is nothing written in the date cell in the Property tab, January 0, 1900 automatically appears in the Summary page.

I am trying to get the Summary page blank until the Property page is filled out. What might be the issue and how can I solve this?

Comment: You can use a custom format to hide the 0 value.  Specify your preferred date format followed by `;;;` .  This will format +ve values as a date and display nothing for -ve, 0, and Text values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that excel likes to treat blank cells as a value of `0` when it is referenced in a formula. Assuming you have a formula of

```
=Property!A1
```

Change the formula to be

```
=IF(Property!A1<>"", Property!A1, "")
```

Basically, the [`IF` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) takes three parts:

- Conditional (if the referenced cell is empty)

  - `Property!A1==""` checks if the cell has a value
  - `Property!A1<>""` checks if the cell is anything but empty
- Value if True (Value of the referenced cell `Property!A1`)
- Value if False (empty string `""`)

I think the date format will try to convert a number to a date, hence the weird date you see, but it doesn't know how to convert a string `""` to a date so it just leaves it "blank".

If you set text as the 'value if false' argument, you'll see the value. You can change this to whatever you want to be displayed.

```
=IF(Property!A1<>"", Property!A1, "DATE NOT SET")
```

Comment: You're incredible. Thank you.

Comment: How can I click and drag this cell down to copy the formula but change "Property" to "a40," "a41," "b09." The issue I am facing is that each name of each property is not in a sequential numerical order. The first five names go as follows: 335, 336, 339, 340, 341, 374, 401, etc. And later letters are placed in front of the numbers and we get a01, a22, a40, etc. All of these numbers can be found in Column A and I am trying to set a date in column E connected to the property page itself (335, 336, 339, etc)...@Cohan